# How can I add new elements to an array inside of another struct array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

**Right now my code looks like this,**

```
    typedef struct veiculo
{
    char matricula[8];
    int nreixos;
    float alturaeixo;
    int tag;
    int classe;

}veiculo;

typedef struct portagem
{
    int nome;
    int kilometros;
    float preco;
    float total_recebido;
    struct veiculo carro[100];
}portagem;

(...)

int encontrar_ult_elemento(struct veiculo v[]){
    int d;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        if (v[i]!= 0)
        d++;
        else
            return d;
    }
}
void guardar_veiculo(struct portagem p[] ,struct veiculo v, int d){
    int i;
        if(v.tag=="1")
            encontrar_ult_elemento(p[1].carro[])=n;
            p[1].carro[n]=v;
        else if(v.tag=="2")
            encontrar_ult_elemento(p[1].carro[])=n;
            p[2].carro[n]=v;
        else if(v.tag=="3")
            encontrar_ult_elemento(p[1].carro[])=n;
            p[3].carro[n]=v;
        else if(v.tag=="4")
            encontrar_ult_elemento(p[1].carro[])=n;
            p[4].carro[n]=v;
        else if(v.tag=="5")
            encontrar_ult_elemento(p[1].carro[])=n;
            p[5].carro[n]=v;
        else if(v.tag=="6")
            encontrar_ult_elemento(p[1].carro[])=n;
            p[6].carro[n]=v;
        else if(v.tag="7")
            encontrar_ult_elemento(p[1].carro[])=n;
            p[7].carro[n]=v;
        else if(v.tag="8")
            encontrar_ult_elemento(p[1].carro[])=n;
            p[8].carro[n]=v;
        else if(v.tag="9")
            encontrar_ult_elemento(p[1].carro[])=n;
            p[9].carro[n]=v;
        else if(v.tag="10")
            encontrar_ult_elemento(p[1].carro[])=n;
            p[10].carro[n]=v;
    }


    int main()
{
struct portagem portagem1;
portagem1.nome = 1;
portagem1.kilometros=14;
portagem1.preco=1.00;
portagem1.total_recebido;

struct portagem portagem2;
portagem2.nome = 2;
portagem2.kilometros=15;
portagem2.preco=1.05;
portagem2.total_recebido;

struct portagem portagem3;
portagem3.nome = 3;
portagem3.kilometros=7;
portagem3.preco=1.20;
portagem3.total_recebido;

(...)



struct portagem p[]={portagem1,portagem2,portagem3,portagem4,portagem5,portagem6,portagem7,portagem8,portagem9};
```

****I have another functions going on, to ask the user to register the veicule, assigning the respective tag etc...I just don't if this is the correct way to do it.
thanks for your help guys! ****

Comment: Your question is not clear. You seem to have a fairly specific question (which is good) but then you dump a whole lot of (incomplete) code and don't explain how/where it relates specifically to the question. It seems you should be able to illustrate your problem with a much shorter piece of code. Please clarify your question. These help pages may be of assistance to you:  [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is the problem you attempted? Aside: why use `struct veiculo` in another `struct` and in a function arguments when you already made a `typedef` as `veiculo `?

Comment: I really feel the need to suggest a switch statement in guardar_veiculo, but that's just personal preference, I supposed.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've tried to do somthing like this:

```
void guardar_veiculo( portagem p[], veiculo v, int d ){
    int n;

    // if v.tag is greater or eaual 0 and less 9
    // then operate on p[v.tag].
    // I assume you meant 0..8 and not 1..10 ( struct portagem p[]= { }; in main )
    if ( v.tag >= 0 && v.tag < 9 )
    {
        // get next free element in p[v.tag].carro
        n = encontrar_ult_elemento( p[v.tag].carro );
        if ( n >= 0 && n < 100 )   // test if n is in range 0..99
            p[v.tag].carro[n] = v; // structure assignment
    }
}
```

Your function `encontrar_ult_elemento` should always return a value:

```
int encontrar_ult_elemento( veiculo v[] ){
    for( int d=0; d<100; d++ ){
        if ( v[d].tag == 0 ) // I assume your criteria is "tag", but I have to guess.
           return d;
    }
    return -1; // no empty element found
}
```

Comment: `struct veiculo` --> `veiculo` because it was already `typedef`.

Comment: You noticed the same for `portagem` too, which (in the question code) also ignores the `typedef` in its field `struct veiculo carro[100];`. Add a footnote?

Comment: ... you edited the range, but doesn't `v.tag="10"` (question) go ***up to eleven*** (CF Spinal Tap)?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, but his array `struct portagem p[]={};` (last line in his code), has only 9 elements.

Comment: thanks man! really appreciate all ur support, and u guys too!

Answer (score 0):

The most important problem with your code is that you are comparing an integer to a string literal which might compile but is incorrect. That's not how you compare strings in [c](/questions/tagged/c), to compare strings you need to do it one character at a time, there is a library function [*`strcmp(3)`*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) to do that.

Remove the double quotes around numbers in the comparisons, and perhaps use a `switch` instead of the many `else if`s.

Comment: thanks man! really appreciate all ur support, and u guys too!